# dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData

Tags: xcode, git, github, terminal

Recently upgraded to most recent version of MacOS, getting the following issue when trying to work with Git. I understand it is something to do with Xcode dev tools not being accessed properly..

So here is what is happening:

```
Mitchells-MBP:~ Mitch$ git
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTDocumentation.framework/Versions/A/../../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTDocumentation.framework/Versions/A/../../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
git: error: unable to locate xcodebuild, please make sure the path to the Xcode folder is set correctly!
git: error: You can set the path to the Xcode folder using /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch
Mitchells-MBP:~ Mitch$ sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/
xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/'
Mitchells-MBP:~ Mitch$ sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/
xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/'
Mitchells-MBP:~ Mitch$ sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/
xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory '/Library/Developer/'
Mitchells-MBP:~ Mitch$ sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/
xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory '/Library/Developer/'
Mitchells-MBP:~ Mitch$
```

I don't know what else to try... really need to upload some stuff to GitHub. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I solved it by reinstalling XCode

Answer (score 0):

I think it's xcode's way to tell that it does not like your OSX version. I have this when trying to run xcode 7 on osx 10.14 Mojave